# I cannot read flipped-vertical qr codes with zxing

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm trying for a while to read QR codes in my application. I can read normal QR codes but now i have to read qr codes flipped vertically. I have thought that when you use the front camera, zxing reads the QR code vertically-flipped. Does anybody know how to change this functionality? Back camera functionanility in the front camera and front camera functionality in the back camera.

I have been looking in the core, but I don't find anything.. :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you read in the image and then pass it to zxing, could you not just flip it yourself if it doesn't find a QR-code (and then try again)?

Comment: zxing does not recognize qr flipped, and the project requires that the application recognizes that kind of qr codes
Thanks for your response! :)

Comment: Try invoking zxing twice, once normal, once flipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QR codes are not valid when mirror-imaged -- rotated yes, but not mirrored. This is why the library will not read them, because they are not valid.

Android does not flip the image data from the front camera when it passes it to an app. (At least, not if the device is working correctly.) It does flip the image when it displays on a `SurfaceView` so that it works more intuitively on screen.

So it will certainly read valid QR codes with the front camera.

Comment: Sorry for disturb another time. Can I modify your core for reading mirrored qr codes? Where do I have to modify? I have seen the class "FinderPattern", but i don't know where i have to modify. :( 

Thank you in advance

Comment: The changes are farther 'upstream'. Look at `PlanarYUVLuminanceSource`. The constructor has a flag that will cause it to flip the image horizontally.